# AlarmMamanger not accurate

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

My application has an AlarmManager set up to trigger every 60 seconds. It triggers a fragment which checks the current time and looks up if there is any Event happening at that time in the app's calendar. 
It was running pretty good until I found out that it skipped one of the events. To check the integrity of the app, I made the fragment write the current time (minutes 0-59) on a text file and see if it does skip any. After carefully digging through the file which was recorded for three days continuously, I found that it does.

> 47, 48, 50, 50, 51, 52, 54, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 0, 1, 2,

This happens randomly anywhere. It happens after 3-4 hours. Here's another example

> 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,

The AlarmManager code doesn't have any problems it seems. Although if the code is skipping a minute OR triggering before the given time has passed there is something wrong somewhere. 
Here is the code I am using on the AlarmManager

```
long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();

    int timeInterval = 60*1000;

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertRec.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, timeInterval, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Questions: 
1) Why is the AlarmManager acting irregularly?
2) How can this be avoided?

Can I reduce the interval time to get around this ? I read the 60 is the minimum interval you need to apply.

Comment: **1** - Because you are targetting API level 19+. **2** - By either targetting API Level 18 or using different methods for setting the PendingIntent/s depending on the OS Version. Please have a peek into the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will
>   shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are
>   new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

This pretty much explains most of it. Also, as far as I know, they have internally added a minimum time limit for repeating alarms ~1min so reducing the interval might not be the best idea.

Hope this helps!